# Can a Dell T410 tower be converted to rack mounting?

Tags: dell-poweredge, rackmount, conversion

I have a Dell T410 which we're moving to a new location. It would be convenient to put it in a rack.  However, I can't figure out if that's possible. Based on [this 2013 reply by a Dell rep in a Dell forum](https://www.dell.com/community/PowerEdge-Hardware-General/Convert-T410-to-rackmount/td-p/4226923), it would appear it's *not* possible, and yet searching reveals [adapter kit PKCR1](http://accessories.dell.com/sna/productdetail.aspx?c=us&l=en&s=bsdr&cs=08&sku=331-0166&mfgpid=202719) which seems like it's designed to adapt a T410 to ReadyRails rails (but in a manner I can't quite figure out).

Thus, my questions: (1) is it possible to take a stock T410 in tower configuration and mount it on rails in a rack, and if so, (2) what parts would be necessary?

Comment: Get the Service Tag and enter it in your local Dell support website and that should tell you the server's capabilities. It may even have resource sheets to show you what to do

Comment: It's been so long since I last touched it, I forgot this was an option. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the [T410 technical guide](http://www.dell.com/downloads/global/products/pedge/en/PowerEdge%20T410%20Technical%20Guide.pdf):

> The PowerEdge T410 is not a rackable system and **does not have a rack kit**. However, the T410 can be stored in a rack using a third-party rack tray.